# What is the meaning of custom program error code 0xc?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-lang, anchor-test, anchor-spl

I am trying to test my program but I am getting `Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0xc`
Can someone suggest the possible issue?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide which:
- Solana network you are on
- spl-token or anchor-spl crate you are using
- anchor version you are using 

0xc is "Invalid instruction" in the token program, so something probably did not serialize right.

Comment: I am using devnet, token-2022 with anchor-spl crate

Comment: Are you getting your instructions and CPI accounts from anchor_spl::token_2022 ? The issue might be that you're using anchor_spl::token.

Comment: no I am using `anchor_spl::token_2022` only, I am trying to call `anchor_spl::token_200::mint_to` present on my contract A, from my contract B

Comment: Can you update the transaction message encoded in base 64? https://explorer.solana.com/tx/inspector

Comment: Or you can update some contract code snippet

Answer (score 2):

This is a total shot in the dark, but `0xc` might refer to `InvalidInstruction` from the SPL token program: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/0e1f6a17bf6c492d0b9ea0abd09de0db16c5fe1c/token/program/src/error.rs#L59

This means that your instruction to the token program is incorrectly constructed in some way.